# code for pagination in wordpress function

Tags: css, wordpress, pagination, styles

i use this code for pagination in wordpress function file

```
function bk_pagination($pages = '', $range = 2)
{  
     $showitems = ($range * 2)+1;  

     global $paged;
     if(empty($paged)) $paged = 1;

     if($pages == '')
     {
         global $wp_query;
         $pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages;
         if(!$pages)
         {
             $pages = 1;
         }
     }   

     if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<nav aria-label='Page navigation example'><ul class='pagination justify-content-center'>";
         if($paged > 1 && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li class='page-item' ><a class='page-link' href='".get_pagenum_link($paged - 1)."'>قبلی</a></li>";

         for ($i=1; $i <= $pages; $i++) 
         {
             if (1 != $pages &&( !($i >= $paged+$range+1 || $i <= $paged-$range-1) || $pages <= $showitems )) 
             {
                 echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class='page-item'>".$i."</li>":"<a class='page-link' href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
             }
         }

         if ($paged < $pages && $showitems < $pages) echo "<li class='page-item'><a class='page-link' href='".get_pagenum_link($paged + 1)."'>بعدی</a></li>";  
         echo "</ul></nav>\n";
     }
}
```

and look like in picture:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dUJYm.jpg)

how i can style number five like other?????

Answer (score 0):

That is because of this line:

```
echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class='page-item'>".$i."</li>":"<a class='page-link' href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."' class='inactive' >".$i."</a>";
```

I am guessing that the current page is in the element of `<li>` while the other pages will be in an  element.

Notice the `<li>` and `<a>` has different classes.

You can have two approach here:

1. Copy the styles of 'page-link' and apply it in 'page-item'
2. The two elements must have the same classes so that they will have the same styles:

`echo ($paged == $i)? "<li class='page-item page-link active'>".$i."</li>":"<a class='page-link inactive' href='".get_pagenum_link($i)."'>".$i."</a>";`

Comment: thank you
but the current tab must different with other tab! ... 
https://cdn3.imggmi.com/uploads/2018/9/20/7412117a02fc5bc84fe9ce019f2cf52c-full.jpg

Comment: If I remember correctly current page number in the pagination has class 'active'. I have updated my answer.

You might want to read this for reference https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links